# Efficient calculation of p(x) * q(x^k)

Tags: polynomials, convolution

Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.
Suppose $q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\lfloor n/k \rfloor$.
Is there an efficient way of calculating $p(x) * q(x^k)$?
Let's assume that multiplying any two coefficients is $O(1)$.

Observe that $q(x^k)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$, and all terms but those at position which is a multiple of $k$ are zero.

I am looking for a way of exploiting the fact that $q(x^k)$ is sparse, and more over, not just randomly sparse, but sparse with a regular distance of $k$.

I am aware of generic polynomial multiplication algorithms such as those based on FFT that run in $O(n \ log \ n)$, but applying this directly makes no use of the above properties. Is something like $O(n + \frac{n}{k} log \frac{n}{k})$ achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the cost of polynomial multiplication be $f(n)$, where the unit is the time of an addition. Then you can see $p$ as the sum of $k$ polynomials of $n/k$ terms, taking every $k^{th}$ terms. You can perform $k$ independent multiplies, taking $kf(n/k)$ operations in total, and regroup the results, requiring $k(2n/k)$ additions.

Ignoring overhead, the total cost is $kf(n/k)+2n$. To obtain a net gain, you need to have

$$kf\left(\frac nk\right)+2n<f(n).$$

With $f(n)=an\log n$,

$$an\log\left(\frac nk\right)+2n<an\log n$$ for $$\log k>\frac2a.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is precisely the decomposition I suspected exists, but didn't think of it myself! I believe there is a small typo and you meant taking every k-th term. For some reason I couldn't edit the post.
Your analysis seems correct, except for the very last bit. I get that $log(k) > \frac{2}{a}$, without the $n$ factor in it. In practice I believe even for $k = 2$ this might be beneficial. Unfortunately it turns out this is $O(n \ log \frac{n}{k})$ and an $O(n+\frac{n}{k} log \frac{n}{k})$ algorithm seems unlikely to exist.

Comment: @plamenko: you are right, I fixed the typos.